# Executing many sub processes in groovy fails

Tags: python, groovy, process

I need to create a script that calls an application (c++ binary) 4000 times. The application takes some arguments and for each call writes a zip file to disk. So when the script is executed 4000 zip files will be written to disk. The application supports multiple threads.

I first created a bash script that does the job and it works fine. But now I need the script to be platform independent. I have therefore tried to port the script to groovy, something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4000; i++) {
  def command = """myExecutable
                 a=$argA
                 b=$outDir"""

  def proc = command.execute()                 // Call *execute* on the string
  proc.waitFor()                               // Wait for the command to finish
  // Obtain status and output
  println "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}"
  println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
  println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}" // *out* from the external program is *in* for groovy

  println "iteration : " + i

}
```

But after 381 zipfiles have been written to disk the script just hangs. Do I need to close the process after each call or something similar?

Here:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management

it says that its known that java.lang.Process might hang or deadlock. Is it no-go to do something like this in groovy?

I will also give it at try in python to see if it gives the same problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the output stream blocking:

```
(1..<4000).each { i ->
    println "iteration : $i"

    def command = """myExecutable
                 a=$argA
                 b=$outDir"""

    def proc = command.execute()
    // Consume the outputs from the process and pipe them to our output streams
    proc.consumeProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )

    // Wait for the command to finish
    proc.waitFor()

    // Obtain status
    println "return code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should close streams belongs to process.

Or, as say @tim_yates you shoul use consumeProcessOutput, or, in concurent solution, waitForProcessOutput, which closes them for you.

For parallel computation you could use smth. like this:

```
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

GParsPool.withPool(8){ // Start in pool with 8 threads.
  (1..4000).toList().eachParallel {
    def p = "myExecutable a=$argA b=$outDir".execute()
    def sout = new StringBuffer();
    def serr = new StringBuffer();
    p.waitForProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    synchronized (System.out) {
      println "return code: ${ p.exitValue()}"
      println "stderr: $serr"
      println "stdout: $sout"
      println "iteration $it"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `consumeProcessOutput` rather than `p.err.text` and `p.out.text`, as these can block

Comment: Thanks for notice! Yes, I missed it. But if we use GPars and concurency, we have a [race condition](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3275), so we should use waitForProcessOutput, as I think.
And u123 asks for concurent solution. Am I right?